# New column in pandas df based on array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Say I have a df like the one below.

```
    num value
0   1   229
1   2   203
2   3   244
3   4   243
4   5   230
```

And an array: `array([ 2, 4])`.

I would like to create a new column for binary variable, such that it is 1 when `num` is equal to the value in the array and 0 otherwise.

```
    num value binary
0   1   229   0
1   2   203   1
2   3   244   0
3   4   243   1
4   5   230   0
```

Wanted to use:
`df["binary"] = np.where(df["num"] == dtemp.num.unique(), 1, 0)`, where `dtemp.num.unique()` is the aforementioned array. But since the lengths of df and array are different - I get the "Lengths must match to compare" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using series.apply() and lambda you can do this.

```
df['binary'] = df['num'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in [2,4] else 0)
```

Reference:

Comment: I was trying `map` but it did not work. But `apply` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

No need to iterate, you can use `isin()` to check membership in your array

```
arr=np.array([2,4])

df['bin']=df['num'].isin(arr).astype(int)

    num value   bin
0   1   229     0
1   2   203     1
2   3   244     0
3   4   243     1
4   5   230     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use itertuples() here.

```
binary = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row[1] in array:
        binary.append(1)
    else:
        binary.append(0)

df['binary'] = binary
```

Comment: This solution does not provide the correct answer though. I haven't tried in my minimal working example but in the original problem it comes short of two ones.

Comment: That's pretty curious. The only reason I could think readily as to why that would be is if something is weird with the data types, but I doubt that's the case. Thanks for letting me know.